# How to turn this mixed Row/Column Table into desired output. (Oracle SQL/Release:Ora12c)

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have this Excel input file getting handed off remotely, and trying to import it into this end result, without any luck. Any help/pointers would be appreciated. So far I've tried Oracle LEAD function to get the first 6 rows to pivot(if that's the right term in this case), having trouble with the rest.

So my incoming data is in this format (I've added the row/line numbers in Column 4 towards the end to get my LEAD function to work).

```
+-----------+--------------+-------+------+
|   Col1    |     Col2     | Col3  | Col4 |
+-----------+--------------+-------+------+
| FYear     | 2019         |       | 1    |
| Office    | ABC          |       | 2    |
| Org       | xyz          |       | 3    |
| Acct      | 11122233     |       | 4    |
| SubAcct   | 555666       |       | 5    |
| Status    | C            |       | 6    |
| 1000      | blahblahblah | $1000 | 7    |
| 1001      | blahblahxxyy | $999  | 8    |
| 1029      | blahblahxxyy | $7676 | 9    |
| .....     | ..........   | ..... | ..   |
| FYear     | 2019         |       | 55   |
| Office    | EFG          |       | 56   |
| Org       | xyz          |       | 57   |
| Acct      | 11122233     |       | 58   |
| SubAcct   | 555888       |       | 59   |
| Status    | C            |       | 60   |
| 1000      | blahblahblah | $4440 | 61   |
| 1001      | blahblahxxyy | $3875 | 62   |
| 1029      | blahblahxxyy | $5029 | 63   |
| ......... | ......       | ....  | ...  |
+-----------+--------------+-------+------+
```

And I'm trying to get it to be this output format.

```
+------+------+------+--------+--------+------+------+--------------+-------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |  Col4  |  Col5  | Col6 | Col7 |     Col8     | Col9  |
+------+------+------+--------+--------+------+------+--------------+-------+
| 2019 | ABC  | xyz  | 112233 | 555666 | C    | 1000 | blahblahblah | $1000 |
| 2019 | ABC  | xyz  | 112233 | 555666 | C    | 1001 | blahblahxxyy | $999  |
| 2019 | ABC  | xyz  | 112233 | 555666 | C    | 1029 | blahblahxxyy | $7676 |
| ...  | ...  | ...  | ...    | ...    | .    | ...  | ...          | ...   |
| 2019 | EFG  | xyz  | 112233 | 555888 | C    | 1000 | blahblahblah | $4440 |
| 2019 | EFG  | xyz  | 112233 | 555888 | C    | 1001 | blahblahxxyy | $3875 |
| 2019 | EFG  | xyz  | 112233 | 555888 | C    | 1029 | blahblahxxyy | $5029 |
| ...  | ...  | ...  | ...    | ...    | .    | ...  | ...          | ...   |
+------+------+------+--------+--------+------+------+--------------+-------+
```

Essentially, I need to turn the first 6 (header rows if you will), into horizontal/repeating values for the line numbers that follow down below them. And then repeat the logic over n over because those header parts keep repeating, with the line number tables below them.

Any pointers / help appreciated !!

P.s:- This is what I've tried/come up with so far.

```
select (CASE WHEN Col1 = 'FYear' THEN Col2 END) New_Col1, 
LEAD((CASE WHEN Col1 = 'Office' THEN Col2 END)) OVER (ORDER BY Col4) New_Col2,
LEAD((CASE WHEN Col1 = 'Org' THEN Col2 END),2,0) OVER (ORDER BY Col4) New_Col3,
LEAD((CASE WHEN Col1 = 'Acct' THEN Col2 END),3,0) OVER (ORDER BY Col4) New_Col4,
LEAD((CASE WHEN Col1 = 'SubAcct' THEN Col2 END),4,0) OVER (ORDER BY Col4) New_Col5,
LEAD((CASE WHEN Col1 = 'Status' THEN Col2 END),5,0) OVER (ORDER BY Col4) New_Col6
from demo_table
where col4 <7;
```

Comment: Rows in a table (in SQL) are not ordered. So, how did you add the numbers in `Col4`? It would make sense to do that in Excel, before importing to a SQL database; if you did it after the export, and you got the right numbers anyway, that is pure luck.

Comment: You're right, I did it before in excel, so I could use the LEAD (order by) to get my query going.

Comment: Interesting problem, and well explained. You included your Oracle version (always very important); it would be even more useful to state the exact version, as in 12.2.0.1, rather than the generic "12c" Oracle uses for marketing. You also showed your attempted code. Much, much better than the vast majority of posters here. Just one request, please: in the future, instead of posting ASCII-formatted tables for your inputs, as you did, it's much more helpful to post test data in the form you can see in Soren Kongstad's answer: `create table` and `insert` statements (or a `with` clause). Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, noted !! I will definitely try to do that next time I post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second the comment that the rows are not ordered in a DB.
Furthermore you do not specify if there can be more than 9 rows for segment.

I have a solution that will work for any number of rows pr segment, if the order is preserved somehow, it needs each segment to start with a 'FYear' in col1, and for the order to be preserved, but doesn't care about if there are exactly three rows after the header rows.

Setup:

```
create table testtbl
(
  col1 varchar2(100)
  ,col2 varchar2(100)
  ,col3 varchar2(100)
  ,col4 int
  )
insert into testtbl values ('FYear'  ,2019,'',1);
insert into testtbl values ('Office' ,'ABC','',2);
insert into testtbl values ('Org'    ,'xyz','',3);
insert into testtbl values ('Acct'   ,11122233,'',4);
insert into testtbl values ('SubAcct',555666,'',5);
insert into testtbl values ('Status' ,'C','',6);
insert into testtbl values (1000     ,'blahblahblah',1000,7);
insert into testtbl values (1001     ,'blahblahxxyy',999,8);
insert into testtbl values (1029     ,'blahblahxxyy',7676,9);
insert into testtbl values ('FYear'  ,2019,'',10);
insert into testtbl values ('Office' ,'EFG','',11);
insert into testtbl values ('Org'    ,'xyz','',12);
insert into testtbl values ('Acct'   ,11122233,'',13);
insert into testtbl values ('SubAcct',555888,'',14);
insert into testtbl values ('Status' ,'C','',15);
insert into testtbl values (1000     ,'blahblahblah',4440,16);
insert into testtbl values (1001     ,'blahblahxxyy',3875,17);
insert into testtbl values (1029     ,'blahblahxxyy',5029,18);
```

Solution:

I first make a grp that spans all of the rows in a sequence, then within that group i find the header values and put them in the first 6 columns. I then add the original 3 columns as col7-9, and finally filter out the rows containing the headers.

```
select 
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9
from
(
select 
   max(case when col1='FYear' then Col2 else '' end)    over (partition by grp) Col1
  ,max(case when col1='Office' then Col2 else '' end)   over (partition by grp) Col2
  ,max(case when col1='Org' then Col2 else '' end)      over (partition by grp) Col3
  ,max(case when col1='Acct' then Col2 else '' end)     over (partition by grp) Col4
  ,max(case when col1='SubAcct' then Col2 else '' end)  over (partition by grp) Col5
  ,max(case when col1='Status' then Col2 else '' end)   over (partition by grp) Col6  
  , col1  col7
  , col2  col8
  , col3  col9
from 
(
select
  col1,col2,col3,col4
  ,sum(case when col1='FYear' then 1 else 0 end ) over (order by col4) grp
from testtbl t 
) a
) b
where  col7 not in('FYear','Office','Org','Acct','SubAcct','Status' )
```

Comment: You're right, I added the row numbers in excel, just to get the LEAD function going. And yes, there can be more than 9 rows in a segment , or less, some of the groups have 50-100 rows per segment and such. Thanks for the response I'll try it out.

Comment: Oh that works like a charm !!! more than the code, the logic is just beaut!! :) got a kick out of the code there. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Oracle 12, you can take advantage of `match_recognize`, which will do quick work of this problem. (In Oracle 11, you can use a join and pivoting, as Plnder Stibbons has shown, but that will be slower.)

```
select fyear, office, org, acct, subacct, status,
       col1 as col7, col2 as col8, col3 as col9
from   input_table
match_recognize(
  order by col4
  measures to_number(fyear.col2)   as fyear, 
           office.col2             as office,
           org.col2                as org,
           to_number(acct.col2)    as acct,
           to_number(subacct.col2) as subacct,
           status.col2             as status
  all rows per match
  pattern ( {- fyear office org acct subacct status -} x* )
  define   fyear   as col1 = 'FYear'  , office  as col1 = 'Office',
           org     as col1 = 'Org'    , acct    as col1 = 'Acct'  ,
           subacct as col1 = 'SubAcct', status  as col1 = 'Status',
           x as col1 not in ('FYear', 'Office', 'Org', 'Acct', 'SubAcct', 'Status')
             or col1 is null
);
```

Note that I gave more meaningful names to the first six columns in the output; you should find better names than `col7, col8, col9` for the last three columns as well. I also converted `fyear`, `acct` and `subacct` to **number** data type, as you probably need them to be. I allow the "already-pivoted" values in `col1` (like `'1000'` etc.) to be *any* values other than the six special values `'FYear', 'Office'` etc. (including the possibility that that value may sometimes be `null`) - this is seen in the definition of rows classified as 'x' in the `define` clause of `match_recognize`.

With your input data, I get the following output:

```
FYEAR OFFICE ORG     ACCT SUBACCT STATUS COL7 COL8         COL9
----- ------ --- -------- ------- ------ ---- ------------ -----
 2019 ABC    xyz 11122233 555666  C      1000 blahblahblah $1000
 2019 ABC    xyz 11122233 555666  C      1001 blahblahxxyy $999
 2019 ABC    xyz 11122233 555666  C      1029 blahblahxxyy $7676
 2019 EFG    xyz 11122233 555888  C      1000 blahblahblah $4440
 2019 EFG    xyz 11122233 555888  C      1001 blahblahxxyy $3875
 2019 EFG    xyz 11122233 555888  C      1029 blahblahxxyy $5029
```

You should probably also convert `col9` to number; I didn't show that, because it depends on what you really have in it. Is it always either `null` or a dollar value (a number preceded by the dollar sign)? Anyway, that's a side issue unrelated to your question, but do consider it.

Another important note: I assume that your "segments" always have the first six rows as the "special" ones, with the exact values in `col1` as you show them in your sample. The remaining rows can have anything in `col1` (other than the special values) **and** the number of such rows can be anything, including none, in which case the corresponding "segment" will produce **absolutely nothing** in the output. If different handling is desired in that special case, it can be accommodated easily, you just need to explain what that handling is.

Comment: ohh I see what you did there ! nice, I'll refactor my code to use match_rec, thanks a ton ! man, this day went from really bad to totally flipping cool :) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Join "traditionally" pivoted rows 1-6 with rows "1000", "1001", "1029" for each row number, based on col4 divided by 9:

```
with 
  d as (select t.*, floor((col4 - 1) / 9) + 1 rn from t),
  a as (select rn, 
               max(case col1 when 'FYear' then col2 end) col1,
               max(case col1 when 'Office' then col2 end) col2,
               max(case col1 when 'Org' then col2 end) col3,
               max(case col1 when 'Acct' then col2 end) col4,
               max(case col1 when 'SubAcct' then col2 end) col5,
               max(case col1 when 'Status' then col2 end) col6
          from d group by rn),
  b as (select rn, col1 as col7, col2 as col8, col3 as col9 
          from d where col1 in ('1000', '1001', '1029'))
select * 
  from a join b using (rn)
  order by rn, col7
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8302a5206a336150097e8da7913b8d2f)</sup>**

Comment: quick thought: instead of `floor(col4 - 1) / 9)` you can use `ceil(col4 / 9)`. This will mark the groups as 1, 2, ... instead of 0, 1, ... but the result is the same, and the formula is just a bit simpler. Keep this in mind, too, when you do in fact want the resulting values 1, 2, ...  -  in that case you would still need to add 1 to `floor()`, but you don't need to add anything to `ceil()`.

Comment: Thanks Ponder Stibbons, I've stored up your code as well. Appreciate it a lot.